# Inconsistency while optimizing distance between parabola and point

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization, conic-sections

### Background

After visiting a plethora of many other related answers on the site, I couldn't answer myself what might be going on over the following scenario, where a relatively simple task is to be done, yet something odd (I believe) is occurring, and so, I'd like to read what others think might be happening here.

### Setup

Considering $\left \{A , C \right \}$ as constants, let $f\left(x\right)=A\,x^2+C$ be a certain parabola, and $P=\left\{0 , 0 \right\}$.

##### Find the shortest distance from $P$ to $f(x)$.

### Progress

Considering the above as an optimization problem, I decided to proceed as follows:

$$d^2=\left(y-k\right)^2+\left(x-h\right)^2$$
$$d^2=\left(A\,x^2+C\right)^2+x^2$$
$$d^2=A^2\,x^4+2\,A\,C\,x^2+x^2+C^2$$
$$\frac{\partial{d^2}}{\partial{x}}=4\,A^2\,x^3+4\,A\,C\,x+2\,x = 0$$
$$\left\{x=\pm{{\sqrt{-2\,A\,C-1}}\over{\sqrt{2}\,A}} , x=0 \right\}$$

Even though inappropriate, partial derivative writing was preferred over usual syntax to avoid symbolic confusion; hopefully it's clear why, without degrading the expression's meaning.

Now, for each of the solutions for when derivative is equal to zero:

$$\left\{d^2=\left({{-2\,A\,C-1}\over{2\,A}}+C\right)^2+{{-2\,A\,C-1
}\over{2\,A^2}} , d^2=C^2 \right\} $$
$$\left\{d^2=-{{4\,A\,C+1}\over{4\,A^2}} , d^2=C^2 \right\} $$
$$\left\{\left| d\right| ={{\sqrt{-4\,A\,C-1}}\over{2\,\left| A
\right| }} , \left| d\right| =\left| C\right|  \right\} $$

And so, I end up with two solutions, respectively $(1)$ and $(2)$.

## The Issue

Attempting to use the above formulas succeed in predicting the extremum values for $d$ for many values, like...

[image]

## But then...

[image]

#### What might be going on? Is there something wrong? Is this expected?

From my point of view, the blue circle should either not exist at all (division by zero), or at least be the same size as the red circle, since blue circle (more precisely, its radius) isn't contributing any useful/true information towards solving the problem stated under these specific values, failing at its basic purpose.

Blue circle obeys $(1)$, while red circle obeys $(2)$.

Comment: Since the problem only requires optimizing a certain value, and as shown by my first example picture, there certainly can be _"...two solutions"_, corresponding to maxima and minima values respectively, as both fulfill the requirements imposed.

Comment: I meant in the second case, which is what the question is about. Anyway, I realize my previous comment was poorly worded, so I removed it. Point remains, however, that in the second case you only have *one* solution, and that is $x=0$ which is in fact one of the solutions you got. But you still have to verify each of them for being a minimum.

Comment: In your second example, if you check the equation you obtained for $x$, you'll see that it has no real solution, which is why the blue circle is meaningless in this case.

Comment: I appreciate you made your point clear @dxiv. So, you're saying there is no problem at all if one of the solutions yielded _invalid_ results when evaluated under specific circumstances? «_Invalid_ values being neither maxima/minima of the problem»

Comment: @A.J There are, indeed, cases where the derived formulas end up stepping beyond $\mathbb{R}$, but whenever such a case arises, and given the limitations of my current plotting software, its corresponding circle is not drawn at all (eg. $d = 4i$), clearing any doubts over which one is a valid solution over the reals. The issue here is finding out why, under specific circumstances, both solutions yield valid values over $\mathbb{R}$, yet one of them appears to be _invalid_, that is, its returned value not being a maximum or minimum value of the problem.

Comment: No, what I meant is that the $x$ is imaginary, not the $d$. You're only checking the equation for d, but my point is that equation is meaningless in terms of your graph if the x-value from which it was derived isn't a real number.

Comment: @Jebyte No, that's not what I said. For smooth functions like your parabola, a critical point (where the first derivative vanishes) is either a local extremum or an inflection point. But you still have to check which one it is. And, before even that, you have to check that it exists at all. In your second case, the first two values of $x$ are not real numbers. Which leaves just the remaining value $x=0$ for you to verify.

Comment: Now then, I just have a last question, result of all of these: **So that means, even through symbolic manipulation, and apparently successful derivation of formulas on weak assumptions, there's always the need to check for possible _tainting_ of imaginary/complex values into final formulas, result of differentiation processes, to avoid apparently _invalid_ cases, like this one?**

Answer (score 0):

The first $x$ solution only exist in $\mathbb{R}$ if:
$$
2AC+1<0
$$
$$
AC<-\frac{1}{2}
$$

If both solutions exist, you get the minimum of $d^2$ for the first solution, and you can probably prove that for $x=0$ you have a saddle point or local maxima.

If the first one doesn't exist according to the condition, you get a minima at $x=0$.

You always have to find the type of extrema for each value of $x$.

Comment: I appreciate you took your time to answer my question. However, I'm not sure if my question was clear to you. I'm not interested in trying to distinguish minimal from maximum values. I'd just like to know why, under certain circumstances, evaluating one of the extrema formulas yield _invalid_ results, that is, returns a value which is not a maxima/minimal value, not even an indefinite value like $x/0$, which would be acceptable (and indeed occurs, as you pointed out).

Comment: Because for one of the extrema you are just getting an useless $x$ value (either a saddle point or local maxima). You are just interested in global values in your case. Remember that when you evaluate a global maxima or minima in a function with domain $A$, you have to evaluate border points too. The 'maxima' or 'minimum' you obtain could just be local.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborated comment. Could you, if possible, elaborate on that even further? Maybe within your answer? I feel like what you've just said goes on the right way towards answering my question, but I'm not sure if I understood your statement completely. I'm sure there must be a way to test whether a certain solution is local or global, but that escapes my current knowledge unfortunately. _Interestingly enough, assuming the **invalid** solution is local, it still intrigues me why such a value doesn't even **touch** the parabola section which is local to..._